# Openlayers 3.5 and GeoJSON

Tags: gis, geojson, openlayers-3

I'm having a problem with OpenLayers 3.5. I'm trying to use the one-off loading strategy to grab features from a GeoJSON file. I'm adding a new layer to an already instantiated map. My code looks like this:

```js
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  url: layerInfo.url,
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
});

var pointsLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: styleFunc
});

that.map.addLayer(pointsLayer);
pointsLayer.setVisible(true);
```

However, nothing shows, and when I examine `pointsLayer.getSource().getFeatures()`, I discover that no features were actually loaded.

So, now I tried to load the features a different way:

```js
var that = this;

$.get(layerInfo.url, function(response) {

  var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(response)
  });

  var pointsLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
    style: styleFunc
  });

  that.map.addLayer(pointsLayer);
  pointsLayer.setVisible(true);
});
```

This DOES work. I'm banging my head against a wall here. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks so much!

Comment: Does a request to `layerInfo.url` even appear in your browser's network tab? The symptoms look a bit like what happens when using asynchronous code in a synchronous manner, but I don't have enough experience with OL3 to help further. If I faced the problem I'd set some breakpoints in browser's debugger and try to trace request all the way to OL's internals.

Comment: A request does go out, and it comes back successfully. And the weird thing is that I've followed all the examples out on the internet to the letter (and it's doubly weird, because when I try to load the sample GeoJSON provided by sample code that works, I don't have a problem loading the features.) That would suggest to me that perhaps there's something wrong with my GeoJSON, except that when I attempt to load it manually my own way, it works. My head is hurting...

Thanks for the reply!

Comment: It can be a projection issue as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I'm loading the data now, "data" is my GJson

```
var wktTraffic = new ol.source.Vector({
});

var trafficLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: wktTraffic,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'blue',
            width: 5
        })
    })
});

function showData(data) {
    var format = new ol.format.WKT();
    var feature;
    $.each(data, function (i, link) {
        feature = format.readFeature(link.geom);
        wktTraffic.addFeature(feature);
    })
    console.log('done load map');
}
```

Comment: Still annoyed that it doesn't work the way it exists in the documentation, but this solution works really well for me. Thanks!

Comment: Its ok, Glad that help you. Let me upvote you instead :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on Juan Carlos' answer, and for future reference, here is a function that creates a layer based on GeoJSON, using Angular's `$http` service :

```
function buildStationsLayer() {

    var geoJsonUrl = config.stationsGeoDataUrl /*+ some parameters....*/ ;
    var source = new ol.source.Vector({});
    var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON();

    var stationsLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: source,
        style: stationStyleFunction //function that styles conditionally depending on resolution
    });

    //manually load the GeoJSON features into the layer
    $http.get(geoJsonUrl).success(function(data){
        for(var i=0; i<data.features.length; i++){
            var feature = format.readFeature(data.features[i]);
            source.addFeature(feature);
        }
    });

    return stationsLayer;
}
```

Still not happy that the documented way does not work though. I don't understand why because the official example uses the source and format and it works :

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'data/geojson/countries.geojson',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
  }),
  style: function(feature, resolution) {
    style.getText().setText(resolution < 5000 ? feature.get('name') : '');
    return styles;
  }
});
```

Source : http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.format.WKT.html

It also worked before the change in 3.5, using `ol.source.GeoJSON`.

Comment: I have same issue. Somehow ReadFeatures to read all at once didn't work for me neither.